# Pulling down images from Parse into an array

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have a table on Parse with a "name" field that includes manufacturer names and a "logo" table that includes .png images as PFFiles in Parse. For some reason when I to add the images into an array nothing happens, but the "name" field populates just fine into a separate array. What am I doing wrong here?

```
//Pulling down Manufacturer names & images from Parse
    var manuQuery = PFQuery(className:"Manufacturers")
    manuQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) Manufacturers.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for thing in objects {

                    self.manuList.append(thing["name"] as! String)
                    //self.tableView.reloadData()

                    let userPicture = thing["logo"] as! PFFile
                    userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData, error) -> Void in

                        if (error == nil) {
                            let image = UIImage(data:imageData!)
                            self.logoList.append(image!)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }

                    })

                }
            }
                println(self.manuList)
                println(self.logoList.count)

        } else {

            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo!)")

        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are there any errors? If that is so, post them. Try error handling the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock block.

Comment: No errors which is odd. When I look at the array after its run it says it's empty. Obviously then when I try to put the photos in indexPath.row it throws me an "array out of range" error because it's trying to put 0 objects into the table

Comment: To make things more interesting, I can add the normal PFFiles to an array and the count will show up. However, when I try to grab the image data, nothing gets added.

Comment: This could be because your data is null or faulty.
Try error handling the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock which makes:
getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                
            } else {
                println(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to load the PFFiles into an array in ViewDidLoad() but then grab the data in cellForRowAtIndexPath to render it. Not 100% sure how that works but it did the trick.